# Is it possible to cover multiple integration test classes via one spring boot test bootstrap (@SpringBootTest)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

My main concern raised with the immense increment of build time while adding more test classes. In my application there are various integration test classes for different controllers and services. Each of this integration test class is equipped with `@SpringBootTest` and by definition it bootstraps the application for testing. The more integration test classes means more bootstrapping  per integration test class and it increases the build time.

My idea is to reduce the number of times bootstrapping for each and ever integration test class. I identify categories of integration test classes which will not affect the execution of one to the other. Therefore, if there is a way for me to bundle number of integration test classes and run with one bootstrap I can get the job done. At the end I can clear the context via `@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)`.

I did some research and figured out `JUnit 5` has test suites and it is working fine for my use-case as long as `@SpringBootTest` is distributed among each unit test class. I want to move `@SpringBootTest` to the test suite class level such that it will bootstrap once and trigger test classes in the test suite.

I would highly appreciate if I can get insights for an approach to do this. Thank you in advance.